# Make text written in a text area display on another page

Tags: html, github

I just want to make text written in a text area display on another page, like a post almost, but only text. I'll link the GitHub site where I want to apply this to so anyone can help.

https://inkintheveins78.github.io/

I couldn't find any other answers on Stack Overflow or W3Schools or Codeacademy or anything, so I'm posting here hoping for some help. Thanks!

Comment: GitHub Pages only allows Static Web Pages. That's means you can not do CRUD works. If you run a backend server as an API then its possible in JavaScript.

Comment: Mark My Answer, It will help others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub Pages only allows Static Web Pages. It can read HTML, CSS & JavaScript Files Only. That's means you can not do CRUD Operations. If you run a back end service for your CRUD Operations using an API then its possible in JavaScript AJAX Calls. As well as you can host Angular & React Applications too.

[More Info](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages)